# AxiosError: Request failed with status code 503 when I try to scrap the web page on digitalocean service

Tags: node.js, web-scraping, axios, digital-ocean

I have a scraping service that scrapes a page. I have developed the project on localhost and there aren't any problems with running it. It works properly on the local. I have cloned it to my digital ocean Linux server, I get ***AxiosError: Request failed with status code 503*** error when I try to run it. I have researched this problem and they said that the problem caused maybe is Axios's headers. Then I have added the headers to the request like the following:

```
const headers = {
  Accept: 'application/json, text/plain, */*',
  'Accept-Encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
  'Accept-Language': 'tur',
  refer: 'https://www.hepsiemlak.com/',
  'sec-ch-ua': '"Google Chrome";v="107", "Chromium";v="107", "Not=A?Brand";v="24"',
  'sec-ch-ua-platform': 'macOS',
  'sec-fetch-dest': 'empty',
  'sec-fetch-mode': 'cors',
  'sec-fetch-site': 'same-origin',
  'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_15_7) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/107.0.0.0 Safari/537.36',
}
```

I have just tried to run it but it still has the same problem. What could be the cause of the error?

Comment: I have tried it on Heroku server but unfortunately, there is still a problem. The problem is the same problem.(AxiosError: Request failed with status code 503). I would appreciate if you know the solution :)